# Running java with arguments from file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to sort a buch of integers from a text file. Is it possible to pass the numbers from the file as (String[] args) to my main method?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

next to the Run button (the green arrow) there's a downwards arrow for selecting the run configuration.

click it, go to run configuration. there you can add a new setup for a java program, and in the tabs you can find "Arguments"

EDIT: to read the text file:

put the path inside the run configuration arguments

now in the public static void main(String[] args) you will want to read the text file. you can read the first line, and then use args = line.split(" ")

this will override the String[] args array. **remember to remove this if you export to jar**, unless you will use the file path as the argument

the code for reading the file is something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
args = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
```